# What is jpath for {"Type":"Ping"} in Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json.net, jpath

I have a simple string from webSockets. And i stuck on jPath for SelectTokens() method. Is there any path which can help me grab $.Type only if it is equal to 'Ping'?

```
var str= @"{""Type"":""Ping""}";
var token = JObject.Parse(str).SelectToken("$.Type =='Ping'");
```

This is c# app and standard Json.Net lib is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the token value after select:

```
var token = JObject.Parse(str).SelectToken("$.Type");
Console.WriteLine(token?.Value<string>() == "Ping");
```

If you have an array in your json you can use [json path filters](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#filters):

```
var str= @"{""root"": [{""Type"":""Ping""}]}";
var token = JObject.Parse(str).SelectTokens("$.root[?(@.Type == 'Ping')]");
```

Next will select the whole property:

```
var token = JObject.Parse(str).SelectToken("$[?($.Type == 'Ping')]");
Console.WriteLine(token);
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in a second way without json modifications?

Comment: Thanks, i spent 3 hours looking for this solution +1